# How to set FIFO and palindrome compare?

Tags: c#, windows, palindrome, fifo

I have this windows application

[image]

1.- So, first  when I Add a number it added to listbox1 but not to list 2.  I need to be add ed to listo 2 to

2.- I need the numbers be added separately... For example if I add number 202, it split on 2 after 0 after 2

3.- I need add button for FIFO, but I don't know how can I program it.

4.-Finally compare one by one it with listbox1 with listbox2 with polindrome method, and if its palindrome show message box, say "they are polindrome", if not, say "number it's not  palindrome.

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        int newvalue;


        if (int.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out newvalue))

        {

            numeros.Add(newvalue);

            listBox1.Items.Add(textBox1.Text);


        }
        else
         MessageBox.Show("insert a number");



        textBox1.Clear();
        textBox1.Focus();

    }
```

Comment: Can you remove the unrelated part from your code and ask your real problem?

Comment: Yes,  only I need that full funcionslly

Comment: OK, you get a good **-1**

Comment: I delete my code i suppossed you dont understand it

Comment: Gerardo Quintana, Is this what you understood from my first comment? arrogance doesn't change anything. You are the one in need, not me.

Comment: BTW: look at the numbers of answers and think "What might be wrong with my question" so that no one answers.

Answer (score 1):

For dealing with this problem you should keep your main data in memory (`List<int>`) and manipulate them using different methods and show the result in the listboxes.

Separating your digits can be done this way :

```
        List<int> SeparateDigits(int n)
        {
            var result = new List<int>();
            while(n>0)
            {
                result.Add(n % 10);
                n /= 10;
            }
            return result;
        }
```

After calling this method you can add the list data to both your listboxes if it's what you want.
(sorry for being late)
Good luck.

Comment: Okayy I'll trying it,  I call you on fb,  sorry if I disturb, I coment my results

Comment: so where I put that code? I have the code that inserts on textbox I show the code on my question, and I don't know why I have a problem with variable "n"

Comment: I think the variable "n", it's "newvalue" but in my code, because this is the value I want to separate, but the question is, how to combinate that codes